# Mathematical induction for inequalities: $\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \cdots +\frac1{3n+1} > 1$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

Prove by induction: $$\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \cdots +\frac1{3n+1} > 1$$

adding $1/(3m+4)$ as the next $m+1$ value proves pretty fruitless. Can I make some simplifications in the inequality that because the $m$ step is true by the inductive hypothesis, the 1 is already less than all those values?

Comment: Please learn a bit of LaTeX and use it. And when you do write inline fractions like $1/(n+1)$, don't omit the parentheses. It will confuse your readers no end. I fixed it for you this time around.

Comment: I agree with @Regret's comment--the general term is not at all obvious. My first inclination was to express the LHS using $\sum$-notation, but I can't do this without knowing how the terms look in general.

Comment: You are adding three instead of one terms when you proceeding to $(m+1)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $1&lt;\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534117/prove-that-1-frac1n1-frac1n2-frac13n1)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** When you increase $n$ by $1$, the sum loses one term and gains three. What is the sum of the three gained terms minus the lost one?

Comment: hmm. Are you referring to something like: 1/(3n+2)+1/(3n+3)+1/(3n+4)−1/(n+1)

Comment: That's it, indeed. The sum of the middle positive term and the one negative term is easily simplified, so start there. You can get fancy and use the AM-HM inequality, or you can get the needed inequality by hand.

Answer (score 0):

More generally
(one of my favorite phrases),
let
$s_k(n)
=\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{kn+1} \frac1{i}
$.

I will show that
$s_k(n+1)>s_k(n)$
for $k \ge 3$.

In particular,
for $n \ge 1$
$s_3(n)
\ge s_3(1)
=\frac1{2}+\frac1{3}+\frac1{4}
=\frac{6+4+3}{12}
=\frac{13}{12}
> 1
$.

$\begin{array}\\
s_k(n+1)-s_k(n)
&=\sum\limits_{i=n+2}^{kn+k+1} \frac1{i}-\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{kn+1} \frac1{i}\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=n+2}^{kn+1} \frac1{i}+\sum\limits_{i=kn+2}^{kn+k+1} \frac1{i}
-\left(\frac1{n+1}+\sum\limits_{i=n+2}^{kn+1} \frac1{i}\right)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=kn+2}^{kn+k+1} \frac1{i}-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{k+1} \frac1{kn+i}-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{kn+2}+\frac1{kn+k+1}+\sum\limits_{i=3}^{k} \frac1{kn+i}-\frac1{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

$\sum\limits_{i=3}^{k} \frac1{kn+i}
\ge \sum\limits_{i=3}^{k} \frac1{kn+k}
= \frac{k-2}{kn+k}
$.

If we can show that
$\frac1{kn+2}+\frac1{kn+k+1}
\ge \frac{2}{kn+k}
$,
then
$s_k(n+1)-s_k(n)
\ge \frac{2}{kn+k}+\frac{k-2}{kn+k}-\frac1{n+1}
= \frac{k}{kn+k}-\frac1{n+1}
= \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}
=0
$.

But

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{kn+2}+\frac1{kn+k+1}-\frac{2}{kn+k}
&=\frac{kn+k+1+(kn+2)}{(kn+2)(kn+k+1)}-\frac{2}{kn+k}\\
&=\frac{2kn+k+3}{(kn+2)(kn+k+1)}-\frac{2}{kn+k}\\
&=\frac{(2kn+k+3)(kn+k)-2(kn+2)(kn+k+1)}{(kn+2)(kn+k+1)(kn+k)}\\
\end{array}
$

Looking at the numerator,

$\begin{array}\\
(2kn+k+3)(kn+k)-2(kn+2)(kn+k+1)
&=2k^2n^2+kn(k+3+2k)+k(k+3)\\
&-2(k^2n^2+kn(k+3)+2(k+1)\\
&=2k^2n^2+kn(3k+3)+k(k+3)\\
&-2k^2n^2-2kn(k+3)-4(k+1)\\
&=kn(3k+3)+k(k+3)\\
&-kn(2k+6)-4(k+1)\\
&=kn(k-3)+k(k+3)-4(k+1)\\
&=kn(k-3)+k^2-k-4\\
&> 0 \quad\text{for $k \ge 3$}
\end{array}
$

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use that
$$\frac1{3n+2}+\frac1{3n+3}+\frac1{3n+4}-\frac1{n+1}=\cdots >0.$$